# jquery get radio button value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

all i want is to use the .get function to retrieve the selected/checked radio button value, i think i got the code right, but the sequence is kinda wrong

```
$.get('burgerorder_check.php', function(data) {
                inputVal = $('input[type=radio][name=timeslot]:checked').val();
            });
```

then after i get the inputVal, i want to reload a particular div with that specific input

```
    setInterval(getData,1000);
    getData();
    function getData(){
    if( inputField ) {
    $("#timeslot").load('burgerorder_check.php?dateselect='+inputField+'&inputselect=a'+inputVal);
    };
```

any help? So far the inputVal value is null :(

Full block of code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var inputField;
        var inputVal;


        $("#dateslot").change(function(){
        inputField = $('#dateslot').val();
        });

        $.get('burgerorder_check.php', function(data) {
            inputVal = $('input[type=radio][name=timeslot]:checked').val();
        });

        setInterval(getData,1000);
        getData();
        function getData(){
        if( inputField ) {
        $("#timeslot").load('burgerorder_check.php?dateselect='+inputField+'&inputselect=a'+inputVal);
        };
        };


});
```

Comment: What is inputField? Is inputVal a global variable? You need to share the complete block of code, this  code part seems incomplete to correctly find the issue.

Comment: i've added the full block of code in, i'm not quite sure about the global variable, i know inputField is not, but in this case, i have 2 pages, which one is use to only generate the radio box form so that i can change it accordingly, but now what i want is to keep it selected by retrieving its value and sending it back again. Or is there another way to do so?

Comment: What I can understand with your comment is that you have a form containing a set of radio buttons. When the user selects a radio button, you want that value to be sent to the server script and keep the radio button selected. Is it correct?

Comment: yes i want it to be kept selected but i am also refreshing that div that load the page every second.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input[name='radio_button_name']:checked').val()
```

Comment: `$('input[type="radio"]:checked').val()` works as well if there's only one radio button name

Answer (score 1):

Try this

I hope to be able to help you

```
Jquery Code:
$("#ssss").bind("change",function(value){
    var test = $(this).children(":checked").val();
    alert(test)
})

HTML Code:
<div ng-app="App" id="ssss">
   <input type="radio" name='test'  value="red">  Red <br/>
   <input type="radio" name='test' value="green"> Green <br/>
   <input type="radio" name='test' value="blue"> Blue <br/>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5qbG6/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$("input[name='RadioButtonId']:checked").val()

$.get('burgerorder_check.php', function(data) {
                inputVal = $("input[name='timeslot']:checked").val()
            });
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work, also i don't need the radiobuttonid to be checked, then it would defeat the radio button purpose right?

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeslot = $("#timeslot:checked").val();
alert(timeslot );
```

Comment: the timeslot is not an id, its a name.

Comment: for radio button, isn't the ID different for each value?